# Edit property names recursively

Tags: javascript, recursion

I have a JS data structure which comes from JSON like this:

```
[
    {
        "eid": "T1",
        "name": "Topic1",
        "children": [
            {
                "eId": "T1.1",
                "name": "subtopic1",
                "children": []
            },
            {
                "eId": "T1.2",
                "name": "subtopic2"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "eId": "T2",
        "name": "Topic1",
        "children": []
    }
]
```

I need to iterate this and construct another structure that looks like:

```
[
    {
        "id": "T1",
        "text": "Topic1",
        "children": [
            {
                "id": "T1.1",
                "text": "subtopic1",
                "children": []
            },
            {
                "id": "T1.2",
                "text": "subtopic2"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "T2",
        "text": "Topic1",
        "children": []
    }
]
```

My code is here

```
// topics = the first strucutre

var treeData=[]; 
for(var i=0,len=topics.length;i<len;++i)
{
    var topicElements=topics[i];
    var subNodes=[];
    var nodes={};
    nodes['id']=topicElements.eId;
    nodes['text']=topicElements.name;

    for (var j =0;j<topicElements.children.length;++j)
        {
            nodesChildren = topicElements.children;
            position = subNodes.length;
            subNodes[position] = new Object();
            subNodes[position]['id']=nodesChildren[j].eId;
            subNodes[position]['text']=nodesChildren[j].name;
        }
    nodes['children']=subNodes;
    treeData.push(nodes);
}
```

It works for one level but if I have to traverse children of T1.1 then it won't work. Can you suggest me a recursive way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this maybe:

```
function redefineData(data) {
    var outData = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var obj = { id: data[i].eid, text: data[i].name };
        if (data[i].children && data[i].children.length) {
            obj.children = redefineData(data[i].children);
        }
        outData.push(obj);
    }
    return outData;
}

var treeData = redefineData(topics);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a generic version in ES6 that I think is a bit simpler:

```js
const renameKey = (oldName, newName) => (xs) =>
  xs .map (({[oldName]: old, children, ...rest}) => ({
    [newName]: old,
    ...rest,
    ...(children ? {children: renameKey (oldName, newName) (children)} : {})
  }))

const fixId = renameKey ('eId', 'id')


const data = [{eId: "T1", name: "Topic1", children: [{eId: "T1.1", name: "subtopic1", children: []}, {eId: "T1.2", name: "subtopic2"}]}, {eId: "T2", name: "Topic1", children: []}]

const treeData = fixId (data)

console .log (treeData)
```

If you don't mind adding an empty `children` array to those that don't have one, you can simplify a bit:

```js
const renameKey = (oldName, newName) => (xs) =>
  xs .map (({[oldName]: old, children, ...rest}) => ({
    [newName]: old,
    ...rest,
    children: renameKey (oldName, newName) (children || [])
  }))
```

If the sample data didn't have a typo, and you actually need to change both `eId` and `eid` to `id`, you can call it twice, once with each spelling.  But if you want to entirely ignore case, then this would require a different technique (...and also possibly lead to problems if you had two different keys that are case-insensitively the same.)